# Code works during F8 step through, but not when ran

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro that works perfectly when ran using "F8" (break mode), but when ran normally, the step below seems to be skipped by the procedure. None of the answers to related questions allow me to solve this issue.
Can anyone tell me what makes the program not to provide the correct result?

```
Option Explicit
Dim wbTO As Workbook
Dim wsEF As Worksheet, wsTO As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer, rn As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, o As Long, oo As Long, v As Long
Sub GenerateEFiche()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   
    Set wbTO = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsEF = Worksheets("main")
    Set wsTO = wbTO.Sheets(1)
    x = Application.Match("Header1", wsTO.Rows(1), False)
    y = Application.Match("Category", wsTO.Rows(1), False)
    o = 0
    oo = 0
    v = 0
    Set r = wsTO.Range(wsTO.Cells(2, x), wsTO.Cells(LastRow, x))
        For Each Cell In r
        rn = Cell.Row
            If Cells(rn, y).Value = "ALPHA" And Not Cell = "" Then
                o = o + 1
            ElseIf Cells(rn, y).Value = "BRAVO" And Not Cell = "" Then
                oo = oo + 1
            ElseIf Cells(rn, y).Value = "CHARLIE" And Not Cell = "" Then
                v = v + 1
            End If
        Next Cell
    wsEF.Range("B25").Value = o
    wsEF.Range("C25").Value = oo
    wsEF.Range("D25").Value = v
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
MsgBox "macro terminated"
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but replacing activeworkbook to thisworkbook might resolve issues cause by multiple open workbooks "Set wbTO = ThisWorkbook" change this line.

Comment: What *step below* seems to be skipped? You've not described your  problem well enough for us to help.

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you have an implicit reference to the `ActiveWorkbook`.  `Set wsEF = Worksheets("main")` should be `Set wsEF = wbTO.Worksheets("main")`.

Comment: As well as the previous comments you also have `Set wsTO = wbTO.Sheets(1)` which is looking at the first sheet in the tab order, but the previous line is to a named sheet - if `Main` is the first sheet in tab order then both variables are pointing to the same sheet.

Comment: Instead of single-step (F8), you could set a breakpoint (F9) at various points in your code and run full speed (F5) as usual. That way you can move your breakpoint further down and eventually spot the reason.

Comment: I would rather not use ThisWorkbook as the code is executed from another workbook than the one I wrote the code in. The step that is not executed is the loop "for each Cell in r" and everything that follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I have found the problem:

I have rewritten the 'for each' part of the code

```
    For Each Cell In r
        rn = Cell.Row
        If wsTO.Cells(rn, x).Value <> "" Then
            If wsTO.Cells(rn, y).Value = "ALFA" Then
                o = o + 1
            ElseIf wsTO.Cells(rn, y).Value = "BRAVO" Then
                oo = oo + 1
            ElseIf wsTO.Cells(rn, y).Value = "CHARLIE" Then
                v = v + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next Cell
```

Which now return the desired result. The correct reference to the cells needed to be added for the formula to work correctly.